# Replacing double backslash with single backslash

Tags: java, file, path

I have a path (Ex. C:\Users\chloe\Documents) but when I want to save them in a property file, it saves it with double slash because of the string: "C:\Users\chloe\Documents" For some reason, it doesn't put `\\` after the C:.
I searched on internet and they were talking about replaceAll:

```
path.replaceAll("/+", "/");
```

But this replaces normal slash and I'd like to know how to do it with backslash...(In java)

Here is how I write to the property file (only what needed):

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
OutputStream output = null;


try {
                output = new FileOutputStream("config.properties");
                prop.setProperty("dir", path);
                prop.store(output, null);
            }catch(IOException e1){
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (output != null) {
                    try {
                        output.close();
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            }

 path = System.getProperty("user.home") + File.separator + "AppData" + File.separator + "Roaming";
```

Comment: It's called *backslash*. Also the reason It's usually replaced with the double one is because the backslash has special meaning in strings

Comment: Your problem is a bit unclear. It looks like you may be trying to fix effect instead of cause of problem. Please clarify it (and use `code formatting` to show ``\`` properly in question).

Comment: You're setting `path` after you write it.

Comment: I'm not I just put it after because it is set in another class...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You only need the `\\` when you hardcode it in a `String` literal. Because `\` is the **escape** character, it becomes a single `\` at runtime. You can also write your paths with `/` as a separator. To be clear

```
String path = "C:\\Users\\chloe\\Documents";
```

creates a `String` that has a value equal to `C:\Users\chloe\Documents` (if you were to `print` it). You could also write

```
String path = System.getProperty("user.home") + File.separator + "Documents";
```

which would then select the `Documents` folder of the user at run-time. Finally,

```
System.out.println("\\\\");
System.out.println("\\\\".replaceAll("(\\\\\\\\)+", "\\\\"));
```

Will output

```
\\
\
```

Escaping `\` in a *regular expression* is counter intuitive.

Comment: If I use normal ones, can I still save files to this location ?

Comment: @RekTek249 If you mean `C:/Users/chloe/Documents`, then yes.

Comment: Oh I will try the File.seperator one

Comment: Your post includes nothing about how you are reading and writing the property file, if that is really your question you should post enough for us to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Doing the advent of code 2015 - Day 8 in scala. Counter intuitive indeed!

Answer (score -1):

```
path.replaceAll('\\',File.separator);
```

may work.  More information may be helpful, such as how you are getting the path and what class it is (are you reading a File path to a path or a string, are you generating the path piece by piece).

Comment: Found char, required String

Comment: path.replaceAll("\\",File.separator); or path.replaceAll('\\',File.separatorChar);

Comment: the second yes, the first is a illegal character